# Can you prevent your biases from swaying your logic if you're aware of them?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, bias, thought

As in the title. 
Assuming you are aware of all your biases,and how they interact with your ideas, can you foresee how your biases will warp your judgement or logic, and stop that from happening?

Living a bias free life sounds like a lot of work though, my curiosity is simply in knowing if it would be possible to do so with the necessary knowledge, or if there is some sort of bias-avoiding killer hidden somewhere in the brain.

It looks like similar questions have been asked before, but none literally answer mine.
Introspection Illusion, IF it affects you only when comparing yourself to others, then it's of no obstruction to my question. 
Superficially, the Introspection illusion doesn't look like a roadblock if all you're considering is "I know i like strawberries. I like no other fruit i tried, so if given the choice between strawberries and other fruit i tried, i will always pick the former."

The Bias Blindspot, superficially doesn't look like a negative answer to my question either. 
Confirmation Bias is a good candidate for a negative answer. (https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/science-choice/201504/what-is-confirmation-bias) As described by the writer, Confirmation Bias is caused by wishful thinking and desires. But what if one was to remove any emotional investment from a belief, if that's even an option? Charles Darwin was a strong advocate of this detachment from information.

Here (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2917255/) are listed some ways to avoid bias in a research setting, but what about normal everyday life? That's what i'm most interested in, and no reseach i was able to find can answer yes or no decisively. After all, everyday life is a flood of information.

If i may use myself as an example, i get slightly sick when i am typing biased arguments or fallacious ones, usually before i actually write them out, but sometimes the revelation of bias comes to me later on.
One example was one time i was talking about abuse, and having been the target of some types of abuse, i recognised beforehand (Because i was getting sick after predicting where my conclusion was going), that i was about to say that all abuse is equally damaging, but only based on my experience, and not on hard data or some experiment's conclusion. My experience was blinding my conclusion and i noticed, but can you do that with every bias out there?

I definitely don't think of myself as avoiding all bias just because very often i feel sick during debates or essays. When i have the information, i can also reliably predict my future behaviour, and if i can't, i just say "I don't know". It would still be useful to know if some research which i can't access because i'm a mere layman said anything about it.

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8596/7001, https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8519/7001, https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/12847/7001

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I took a look at the links, but none actually answer what i want, i hope the Edit i just added is helpful.

Comment: Just a quick Google search: https://greatergood.berkeley.edu/article/item/three_ways_mindfulness_can_make_you_less_biased